# Mongoose - Cannot create model with submodels

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, database

I have a model and some submodels, they are linked via the parent's ID, but I cannot create the parent and then the children, and if I do it the other way around, the children are linked to nothing.

Here's my code :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var personalDataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 form_id    : {type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : FormModel},
 first_name : String,
 age        : Number,
 gender     : String,
 nationality: String,
 adress     : String,
 birth_date : String,
 CNP        : String
})

var contactDataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 form_id    : {type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : FormModel},
 phone      : String,
 mail       : String,
 facebook   : String
})

var formSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 _id : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
})

var PersonalData  = mongoose.model('PersonalData',personalDataSchema),
ContactData   = mongoose.model('ContactData',contactDataSchema),
FormModel     = mongoose.model('FormModel',formSchema);

module.exports = FormModel;
```

Comment: Not the slightest idea what you are asking. What do you expect to happen? MongoDB is **not** a relational datastore, and therefore has no built in handling for referential integrity. That should be pretty clear, but you seem to expect this to be enforced somehow. Perhaps you should consider you are using the wrong datastore for your expectations.

Comment: You're trying to use the PersonalData model, not the FormModel. It should be `module.exports = PersonalData;`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be doing this in reverse. If you want to be able to load a form and then have that populate contact data and personal data (as parts of the form) then you should create your Form Schema like this:

```
var formSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  contactData: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'ContactData'
  },
  personaldata: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'PersonalData'
  }
});
```

Then, when you design your API controller to load a form, you'd use something like this:

```
var id = req.params.id; // or get the id from somewhere
FormModel.findById(id)
.populate('contactData personalData')
.exec(function(err, form) {
  if (err) {
    next(err); // assuming you have error handling middleware
  } else {
    res.json(form);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working. I can't figure out how to save one though.

Comment: 1) Create a ContactData document and save its ID in a variable
2) Create a PersonalData document and save its ID in a variable
3) Create a Form document and save the two object Ids in the appropriate spots

Comment: `var form = new FormModel({
  contactData : contactDataID,
  personalData : personalDataID
});
form.save(function(err, form){...dostuff...});`